# Conflicting output for the same ruby code in irb and pry

Tags: ruby, irb, pry

I do the following in irb and have also tried out the same code in pry

```
class Number < Struct.new(:value)
end

class Number
  def to_s
    value.to_s
  end

  def inspect
    "<<#{self}>>"
  end
end
```

Now, if i do `Number.new(2)`, it correctly returns `<<2>>` in irb, but in pry it incorrectly returns `#<struct Number value=2>` . Why is this so ?

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with `pry` (I've never used it until just now), but the obvious answer to your question is: because `pry` isn't calling `inspect` on your object.  You can manually call it, and it works as expected:

```
Number.new(2).inspect
# => "<<2>>"
```

My question was: why isn't `pry` calling `inspect`, and what's it doing instead?  Looking at [the code](https://github.com/pry/pry/blob/master/lib/pry.rb), it looks like it calls `pretty_inspect` instead.  There may be a smarter workaround, but the simplest thing that comes to mind for me is to just alias `pretty_inspect` to `inspect` for `Number`:

```
class Number
  alias_method :pretty_inspect, :inspect
end

Number.new(2)
# => <<2>>
```